# increase the height of the checkout text area in woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I need to increase the height of the text area 'Target objectives' at the checkout page. How can I do this with CSS?

The link to the site: https://www.instaboosting.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=211

I tried:

```
.woocommerce-billing-fields #billing_myfield14 {
    height: 13em; // Set your height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is working. Some how your code was not working in browser.

```
.form-row-wide #billing_myfield14 {
    height: 13em;
}
```

Check this image [image]

Comment: which browser ?

Comment: chrome, firefox, ie

Comment: it's working in chrome.May be some of your plugin or theme styles  may be overriding your style @leeuwtje

Comment: You see a bigger target objective field in chrome? Can you send me a printscreen?

Comment: @leeuwtje There is a bigger target objective when i apply the style. Scrennshot included in my answer

Comment: When I make the change online in elements it shows the bigger text box, but when I add the text to .css it won't show.

I added the text field with a plugin so maybe it is overiding the theme style. How can I overcome this problem? So they show theme style instead of plugin style.